# Pass variables at queue time to build when triggered by continuous integration

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-definition

In VSTS I have a build definition configured to use Continuous Integration. In this definition I defined some custom variables which are allowed to set at queue time. However, I only can set these variables when I manually trigger a build.

Is there a way to set [these variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InuLv.png) each build when using Continuous Integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to set these at queue time. They will take the default values.

Comment: I really dont see how that would even be posible. It's an automated build... Where would you expect to enter the values?